# warning: 2 reduce/reduce conflicts [-Wconflicts-rr] in yacc grammar

Tags: c, parsing, bison, yacc

I have the following `yacc` grammar:

```
%{
#include  <stdio.h>
extern FILE* yyin;
extern char* yytext;

%}

%token VAR ID_NAME TYPE_STRING TYPE_BOOL TYPE_NUMBER
%token CONST VALUE_STRING VALUE_BOOL VALUE_NUMBER

%%

program
    : declarations
    ;

declarations
    : declaration
    | declarations declaration
    ;

declaration
    : var_declaration
    | const_declaration
    ;

value
    : VALUE_BOOL
    | VALUE_STRING
    | VALUE_NUMBER
    ;

assignment
    : ID_NAME '=' value
    ;

assignments
    : assignment
    | assignments ',' assignment
    ;

id_list
    : ID_NAME
    | id_list ',' ID_NAME
    ;

declaration_expression
    : assignments
    | id_list
    | assignments ',' declaration_expression
    | id_list ',' declaration_expression
    ;

var_declaration
    : VAR ':' type declaration_expression ';' { printf("%s var\n", $1);  } 
    ;

const_declaration: CONST ':' type assignments ';' {printf("const\n");}
    ;

type: TYPE_NUMBER 
    | TYPE_STRING
    | TYPE_BOOL
    ;

%%
void yyerror (char const *s) {
    fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv[])
{

    yyparse();
    return 0;
}
```

It should describe a little language that allows variables and constants declarations of the form: `var:<type> <variables_names or variables_initializations>` and `const:<type> <constants_initialization>`.

I want to add support for the following syntax:

```
var:<type> var1, var2=<value>, var3;
```

Something like this: `var:<type> (<variables_names>|<variable_initializations>)+`.

To accomplish that I've added the following modifications to my grammar:

```
assignments
    : assignment
    | assignments ',' assignment
    ;

id_list
    : ID_NAME
    | id_list ',' ID_NAME
    ;

declaration_expression
    : assignments
    | id_list
    | assignments ',' declaration_expression
    | id_list ',' declaration_expression
    ;
```

Which I thought will enable the `(<variables_names>|<variable_initializations>)+` part. But I get a `reduce/reduce` conflict, due to these lines:

```
    | assignments ',' declaration_expression
    | id_list ',' declaration_expression
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think your first snippet is after the non-working modification. If you still have the working version kicking around, it would be helpful.

Comment: @rici that's the last version that worked http://pastebin.com/xb9V3N8G. However, it does only support variables declarations of the form: `var:<type> <variables_names> | <initializations>`. It doesn't allow mixing  `variables_names` with `initializations`.

Comment: I thought that's what it would look like but I wasn't sure. Thanks. It would be better to edit your question, though, for clarity. "I used this definition of declaration_expression: " (from pastebin) but I wanted to change it so that `var` declarations could be a list of mixed items, either IDs or assignments. So I changed it to: " (from current question), and that gave me reduce/reduce conflicts..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to allow a mixture of bare variable names and variable initializations in a `var` declaration, and only initializations in a `const` declaration. That's quite straight-forward:

```
initialization : ID '=' value
init_list      : initialization | init_list ',' initialization
init_or_id     : initialization | ID
init_or_id_list: init_or_id
               | init_or_id_list ',' init_or_id

const_declaration: CONST ':' type init_list
var_declaration  : VAR   ':' type init_or_id_list
```

What you did wrong was to make a mixed list by extending a mixed list with *lists*, rather with *items*. That's ambiguous, so it results in a reduce/reduce conflict.

The above works (as did your original) because `init_list` and `init_or_id_list` can never appear (as non-terminals) at the same point in a derivation. One of them unambiguously follows the `const` keyword and the other unambiguously follows the `var` keyword. That's fortunate, because a list of pure assignments would satisfy both productions, which would create a reduce/reduce conflict if they shared a context. That problem is also solvable, and since it occasionally arises, I'll add the solution although I emphasize that it is *not relevant* to this particular question. (It might be relevant to some later reader with a similar issue, though.)

To make the two possible list syntaxes unambiguous, it is necessary to ensure that the potentially pure assignment list is always the derivation of a different production from the mixed list. So we could write:

```
init_list: initialization | init_list initialization
init_or_id_list: ID
               | init_list ',' ID
               | init_or_id_list ',' init_or_id
```

Now, an `init_or_id_list` necessarily contains at least one `ID` item, so it cannot be confused with `init_list`. But now we use the final result, we need to remember that a context which accepts a mixed list needs to allow both list possibilities:

```
pure_list: init_list
mixed_list: init_list | init_or_id_list
```